# Template methods in a DLL class C++

Tags: c++, templates, dll, compilation, shared-libraries

I'm implementing a DLL in C++ and in my library I have a class which contains a template method. 
For example

```
class A : public IA
{
public: 
 A() { /* constructor stuff */ }
 template <typename T> void foo { /* foo does stuff */ }
};
```

Now, since templates are resolved at compilation time, if I **never** invoke *foo* in my library but it's meant to be invoked **only** in the project that uses the library, what happens? 
From my understanding, when I compile the DLL, foo won't be saved in the virtual method table with any type, thus, the invokation in the target project may cause some kind of unexpected behavior. Can anyone confirm this and explain it in more details ? Thanks

Comment: Probably of interest: [Class Template - Explicit Instantiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation)

Comment: Not really related to templated method, but inlined one. In the same way A's constructor would probably be called from project, and not from library.

Comment: Pretty much the same as if you put the template methods implementation in a source file then use it from others. You will get a link error if it can't find an instantiation for the type.

Comment: *"foo won't be saved in the virtual method table with any type"* Wording is unfortunate, as *virtual table (vtable)* and `virtual` has other meaning related to polymorphism and inheritance.

Comment: Ehi @Jarod42 , yeah, I forgot to tell that the header which contains *A* won't be included in the target project. To create *A* I use a dedicated exported method, which returns the interface of *A*. FireLancer, the point is that the DLL and the target project compiles with no error

Comment: My point about inlined methods is still valid (until especially marked as exported).